# I want to loop 2d array in PHP

Tags: php, loops

here is my code

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($header);
echo '</pre>';
```

and here is the output

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [A] => Name
            [B] => rollnumber
            [C] => class
            [D] => marks
        )

)
```

I want to read the all array like I want to display 
Name rollnumber class marks in table td using loop any help? thanks

Comment: use foreach.that's it.

Comment: You can use `foreach` twice as `foreach($ar as $key => $value){foreach($value as $k => $v){echo $v."<br>";};}`

Comment: Please, try to solve the problem yourself first. It's not that hard.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh You're right .. Expecting answer :)

Comment: thanks .for your response uchiha

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
foreach($header as $key => $value){ // start $header array loop
if(is_array($value)){ // check if the $value is another array 
    foreach($value as $k => $v){ // start $value array loop
        echo $v.'<br>'; // output $v 'Name rollnumber class marks'
    }
 }else{
    echo $value.'<br>'; // in your case $value is array but you will be able to use like array(1=>array(), 2=>string) the 2 will be the output without a foreach loop
 }
}
```